# How to undo changes to an array after passing to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

Is there any way to undo the actions or get the original array after I changed the array as shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int array[]){

    array[2] = 20;

    //do some extra work
    return;
}

int main(void){

    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    function(array);

    // code which has to use original array 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not make another array b equal to a and perform function on it, since you need both arrays, the on before and after func.

Comment: @Kartik_Koro The above small code is just an idea. What if the array is huge and making many copies will waste space.

Comment: If you want to *change* the array, and you want the *original* array too, I don't think you can really avoid doing some sort of copy...

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: Basisally, there are not much solutions with an array. Copy it or save what/where was changed.

Comment: "What if the array is huge and making many copies will waste space." - Then don't change the array. You can't have it *both* ways. If you feel up to the task of authoring a memory-journalling system, go nuts, but using the base facilities of the language, a copy of *something* has to be made *somewhere*.

Comment: Where is the array coming from? Can you just 'reload' it from that source after modification?

Comment: Well you will have to make *some* sort of copy. You simply can't have two values one old and one new for 1 variable. IF you don't want to copy the whole array for space reasons, see if you can just pass the array to function() and extract elements you want to change in it, and store their indices and changed values in a map. Or something similar. This can help you save space if you're not changing the array too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pack two 32 bit integers (old / new) into a 64 bit integer, example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void function(int64_t array[])
{
    array[2] = (array[2] << 32) | 20;
}

void printarr(int64_t array[], size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (int32_t)(array[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int64_t array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    size_t i, n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    function(array);
    puts("After function:");
    printarr(array, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] >> 32 != 0) /* Changed */
            array[i] = array[i] >> 32; /* Undo */
    }
    puts("Original values:");
    printarr(array, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
After function:
1 2 20 4 5 
Original values:
1 2 3 4 5
```

Note:

Of course you can pack two 16 bit integers in a 32 bit integer if you are using short values in order to save some space.

To be portable use `PRId32` format (defined in `<inttyes.h>`) for `printf` and `int32_t`:

```
printf("%"PRId32" ", (int32_t)x);
```

Another method:

If those changes are made sequentially over positive integers you can change the sign (to identify a change) and store only the changes using `realloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *value;
    size_t length;
} t_undo;

void function(t_undo *undo, int array[], int index, int value)
{
    undo->value = realloc(undo->value, sizeof(int) * (undo->length + 1));
    /* check realloc */
    undo->value[undo->length++] = array[index];
    array[index] = -value;
}

void printarr(int array[], size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", abs(array[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    t_undo *undo;
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    size_t i, j = 0, n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    undo = malloc(sizeof(*undo));
    /* check malloc */
    undo->value = NULL;
    undo->length = 0;
    function(undo, array, 2, 20);
    puts("After function:");
    printarr(array, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] < 0) /* Changed */
            array[i] = undo->value[j++]; /* Undo */
    }
    puts("Original values:");
    printarr(array, n);
    free(undo->value);
    free(undo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess the point of saying "no secondary array or temp file" is to save memory, so using 64-bit int instead of 32-bit int where 32-bit number is stored sort of defeats this purpose. But I like the idea, hadn't thought of something like this :D

Comment: Kartik, yes, you are right, but there is no way to "remember" the old value, must be stored somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

Making it short: No. You cannot have your operations reverted - Not in a simple way anyway. What you probably want is to have a local copy of your data in your `function()`. You could do this by creating a new array and copy it to your first one:

```
int array[5] = whatever;
int array_copy[5];
memcpy(array_copy, array, 5*sizeof(int));
function(array_copy);
//You have your array now unchanged
```

If you really don't wanna do that, there's another way of enclosing your array into a struct and let the compiler synthesize a copy operation for you. However there's a serious downside for this one since for big such struct you may end up wasting your stack.

```
struct MyArray {
    int array[5];
};

void function(struct MyArray m) {
    //This will create a local copy of m
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        m.array[i] = i + 1;
    }
}

void initialize(struct MyArray* m) {
    int i;
    assert(m != NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        m->array[i] = i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct MyArray m;
    int i;

    initialize(&m);
    function(m);

    //Your m here will be untouched

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int array[]){
    array[2] = 20;
}

void save(const char *filename, const void *data, size_t size);
void undo(const char *filename);

int main(void){

    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    save("save_2", &array[2], sizeof(int));//array[2] save to file
    function(array);
    undo("save_2");//restore

    save("save_all", array, sizeof(array));
    function(array);
    undo("save_all");

    // code which has to use original array 
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    remove("save_2");
    remove("save_all");

    return 0;
}

void save(const char *filename, const void *data, size_t size){
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(&data, sizeof(void *), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&size, sizeof(size_t), 1, fp);
    fwrite(data, size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);、
}

void undo(const char *filename){
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    void *data;
    size_t size;
    fread(&data, sizeof(void*), 1, fp);
    fread(&size, sizeof(size_t), 1, fp);
    fread(data, size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```